# GUI busy message

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I asked this q before but may be I was not clear so I am posting again. I have a gui. When I press "button1" my gui starts serial comm. I send some commands and receive some data. Once I press "button1" I am in the other thread (other than GUI thread) for 3,4 sec untill data is fully transferred. **What I want** is a dialog box, pop up or some thing like that (showing a busy message) to appear infront of my gui when I press the button1 and this pop closes automatically in the other thread in which serial communication is taking place when the whole data is transferred.

Some people suggested back ground worker but I was not clear.

An good explanation or a way to do it considering my scenario ?

Thanks

Comment: are you using windows forms or wpf?

Comment: ok thanks for the feedback. I would not do it again. @animaonline I am using windows forms application

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with the following code:

```
  public partial class frmWait : Form
{
    private BackgroundWorker worker;

    public frmWait()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.worker = new BackgroundWorker
            {
                WorkerReportsProgress = true
            };
        this.worker.RunWorkerCompleted += WorkerOnRunWorkerCompleted;
        this.worker.DoWork += WorkerOnDoWork;
        this.worker.ProgressChanged += WorkerOnProgressChanged;
        this.worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void WorkerOnProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Update UI or something else
    }


    private void WorkerOnDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // Do background-stuff here
    }

    private void WorkerOnRunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Actions after BackgroundWorker is done
        Close();
    }
}
```

in the form with button1, in the click-event of the button you just have to:

```
frmWait wait = new frmWait();
wait.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: In your comments "//Do background-stuff here //Update UI or something else" what to do you mean here. I mentioned that I have my serial comm in another thread so how your code integrates with it. Thanks

Comment: In the WorkerDoWork-Part you can check if your other tread is alive. If yes, then wait.